# Can you use a Sass variable in a CSS shorthand property?

Tags: css, sass

I want to specify a border color for my h1 elements using a CSS shorthand property that contains a Sass variable but I'm not getting a border color.

```
// _variables.scss
$dark-blue: #1D1E23;

// style.scss
@import 'variables';

h1 {
  border: 1px $dark-blue solid;
}
```

Is this possible in Sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed the order up a little ;)

`border: [style] [width] [color];`

```
$var: #fff;


h1 {
  border: solid 1px #{$var};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your civil, non-snarky answer.  Greatly appreciated!